# 2D variance in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix

`A2=128x128 double`.

I want to calculate the variance.

`Variance [ A2([i]+1 ,[j]+1) , A2([i]+2 , [j]+2) ]` `i` and `j` are coordinates of pixels and `[]` the real part of a complex number.

How can I calculate?  `Variance [ A2([i]+1 ,[j]+1) , A2([i]+2 , [j]+2) ]` in MATLAB ?

Comment: `Variance` is a variable or just you want to compute *variance* of the latter?

Comment: i just want to compute variance .

Comment: You can't have variance of two numbers like var(1,5), you must include more samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have variance for just two numbers (elements of `A2`).

You can do this,

```
A2=double(imread('cameraman.tif'));
varA2 = std2(A2).^2;
```